# Disk usage goes to 100%

Tags: windows, hard-drive, dell-inspiron

The Disk usage in my Dell Inspiron 15R 3537 with 8GB ram, 1 TB HDD, i7 4th gen, is showing 100% after the initial boot up. What should I do to rectify this problem !!

Answer (score 1):

Open up Resource Monitor, and see which process exactly is using the Disk for 100%, Most probably its a Virus Scanner, Microsoft Security Essentials does that from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Two more options:

1. faulty hard drive
2. encryption software running in the background and encrypting your drive - if this is the case, you should see some notification about this.