# HDD Read Write Stutter with click sound. Usage goes to 100% every stutter?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

System:

- Processor : Intel® Core™ i5-4460 Processor (6M Cache, up to 3.40 GHz)
- Motherboard : Gigabyte GA-B85M-HD3
- Operating System : Windows 10 Pro
- Harddisk: Seagate ST1000DM010-2EP102 1 TB 7200RPM

I HAVE REPLACED MY HDD WARRANTY 4 TIMES that the seller is thinking I am trying to intentionally break it. 
My HDD sometimes produced "clicking" sound. Every time the sound comes up, this is what happened:

1. Every program (music player) or games (while loading) stopped.
2. The HDD Stopped Spinning and immediately start spinning again.
3. In Task Manager, HDD Usage went full 100% with write and read at 0 Kb/s.
4. It takes almost always the same amount of time every click to be responsive again.
5. Sometimes fixed by hot unplugging the power cable and replugging it to HDD

THIS HDD IS 3 DAYS OLD. I have just exchanged it for warranty 3 days ago and this symptoms is always happening to all every HDD I exchanged. When this happen, it keep stuttering and clicking until about an hour. This only happen on heavy load (game updating, software downloading).
Things I have tried:

1. I have tried this suggestion: [Disk usage goes to 100%](https://superuser.com/questions/763898/disk-usage-goes-to-100)
2. Ran HD Tune Pro Trial to check for error block and 100% safe
3. CrystalDiskMark reads OK for every aspect. Power on hours is only 70 Hours.
4. Bought and put up Stabilizer and UPS Before putting this HDD
5. Install and update Motherboard's driver

I have ran out of clues. What should I do?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73182/discussion-on-question-by-wiryandi-p-hdd-read-write-stutter-with-click-sound-u).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, seems like some unstable voltage from main power makes the PSU unstable. Bought new Power Supply and now the problem disappear completely.

Answer (score 1):

Change the power cable that is plugged in to the hard drive.  Your system should hopefully have additional unused power cables available.

This sounds exactly like the drive is intermittently losing power. You can confirm this by simply wiggling the power connector and wire running to your hard drive while the system is powered up. I’d be willing to bet you’ll hear the hard drive shut down.

I’m not fond of Seagates, but even I don’t think that many would go bad that often. They do run especially hot though, so it is also a possibility the drive is getting too hot. You should be able to check that by feeling the hard drive after a period of usage. If it feels hot to the touch it could be overheating.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I forgot to mention that I have already tried switching to new cable (SATA and power cable) several times. I'm yet to switch the Power Supply though, going to bring the HDD to my friend's PC to test it tomorrow.
Regarding overheating, my room is air-conditioned and my PC case is almost always open and cleaned up regularly.